# Clicking a node in the Sitecore tree makes all other nodes disappear

Tags: sitecore

I'm encountered a weird issue with new Sitecore user accounts. I set their permissions correctly, giving them access to read, write, create, etc the content items/folders they need and the Media Library. When they user logs in and clicks any of the 5 nodes in the tree (or their children) the Sitecore tree/navigation will hide all other nodes.

So if they click an image in the Media Library, the Sitecore tree will focus on the Media Library and not show the Content, System, Templates, etc nodes.

I've tried adding every single role in my company's Sitecore system to a test user and that didn't change a thing, it still happens. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Sitecore version?

Comment: Also: Did  you ensure, your users have permission to the /sitecore root node?

Comment: I'm working with Sitecore 7.0. The user has read access to the Sitecore node and all of it's child nodes, what else would it need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Content Editor, click the Content Editor menu, and then click Application Options.  Click View tab and check "Show Entire Content Tree"

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_content_editor/customize_the_content_editor

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your URL if it contains ro=/sitecore/media when you click an image media item? Also let please let us know which version you using of Sitecore? Have you made any changes to link manager ?

Comment: It does not. We have made changes to Link Manager but I am relatively new to this project so I am not sure how those changes affect this situation

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a session issue.  The Sitecore shell does not like running in a stateless load balanced environment, and the tree in particular manages it's context in session state.  If you have more than one server for authoring behind an NLB make sure you have sticky sessions enabled.  Otherwise check to make sure your session state setup is properly configured.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be this. I mean, this problem did occur on an Authoring server behind an NLB, but I just tried it on the QA server which is completely separate, gave a test user the same permissions, and the problem persists..

Comment: Can you use your browser dev tools to observe the ajax requests when expanding the tree and post the results? i.e. 200s / 500s ? If latter then any messages in the body.